# Image is not displaying in header

Tags: magento-1.9, css, header

we are trying to add 4th icon after 3 icons in header

[image]

but whereever i placed below code in header.phtml , its not working.

4th icon is displaying before 3 icons. i want to display after 3 icons.

**code for 4th icon.**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/search_16.png');?>" alt="Search">
```

**header.phtml**

```
<div id="header">
<header id="header" class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header-container">
        <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="large" />
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrcSmall() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="small" />
        </a>

        <div id='hideshow'><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/search_16.png');?>" alt="Search"></div>

        <?php // In order for the language switcher to display next to logo on smaller viewports, it will be moved here.
              // See app.js for details ?>
        <div class="store-language-container"></div>

        <!-- Skip Links -->

        <div class="skip-links">
            <a href="#header-nav" class="skip-link skip-nav">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Menu'); ?></span>
            </a>

            <a href="#header-search" class="skip-link skip-search" id="hideshow1">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Search'); ?></span>
            </a>

            <div class="account-cart-wrapper">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getAccountUrl(); ?>" data-target-element="#header-account" class="skip-link skip-account">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <!-- <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Account'); ?></span> -->
                </a>


                <!-- Cart -->

                <div class="header-minicart">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_head'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <!-- Navigation -->

        <div id="header-nav" class="skip-content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Search -->

        <div id="header-search" class="skip-content desktop-only">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Account -->

        <div id="header-account" class="skip-content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!--<div id="header-search" class="desktop-only">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        </div>-->
</header>


<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must edit the following code css:

```
<div id="hideshow"><img alt="Search" src="http://example.com/skin/frontend/rwd/theme/images/search_16.png"></div>
```

Currently you have the following css:

```
#hideshow {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 121px;
    top: 29px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

remove `right: 121px;`

or

```
right: 0px;
```

brgds.

Comment: download https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ with firefox, is the best tool for css editing.

Comment: this code is not available now, <div class="store-language-container"></div> , you have to restore that piece of information in header and check in css if currently is not displaying -> display:none

Comment: i added this code, now its displaying below 3 images. i want to display `currency` right next to 3 images.

Comment: now is displaying currency indian rupees

Comment: but its displaying below 3 images, i want to display right next 3 images. please refresh page & check.

Comment: now is displaying a static html page "download app"

Comment: even icons are interchnaged once i removed `right: 121px;` but i want to keep icons in same positions.